# Plugin that detects images in a webpage like Imgur

Tags: javascript, crossrider

I am trying to make a cross-browser plugin that detects images from a webpage like imgur and pinterest. I have been looking at crossrider...is that a good option? the API is tricky to understand. If anyone has experience with something like this or can give me a good starting point, i would really appreciate it.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: i understand that :) my aim is to write a plugin that can detect images in a webpage. i tried following the tutorial here: http://blog.crossrider.com/post/52302194099/from-bookmarklet-to-extension-in-just-5-minutes
but nothing was working. i was hoping if someone can suggest what functions in the API i should focus on to help me with this problem. this is my first time using crossrider.

Answer (score 1):

In general, the Crossrider framework supports cross browser extension development and provides APIs and plugins to make it easier, but at the end of the day it's up to you to evaluate the framework and see whether it meets your needs. The tutorial you quoted relates to creating a bookmarklet extension and does not pertain to images.

For your specific requirement, there is an images plugin (see the [Plugins page](http://crossrider.com/developer/plugins)) that facilitates working with images on a page.

As @Lix correctly mentions, this is not the place to ask such general questions and hence I recommend that you start by reading the Crossrider [docs](http://docs.crossrider.com) and searching the [forum](http://getsatisfaction.com/crossrider). If you have any further general questions, email them to support@crossrider.com.

Of course, if you have any specific code related questions, Stack Overflow is another great place to get answers ;-)

[**Disclosure**: I am a Crossrider employee]

Comment: thank you...i am looking at he images plugin now...but i dont know how to use it along with my extension and background code :(

Comment: You can take the sample code provided when adding the plugin to the extension and paste it in the extension.js file. Then simply install and see the messages from the code in the browser console.

Comment: yes, i found the info yesterday....thank you. i also send u a message on the crossrider forum about console.log not working on firebug console in firefox. the web console was working thankfully, but i hope u can fix it :) btw, crossrider is awesome!!! (even though the safari restriction sux :( )